# How do we prove this nested radical solution?

Tags: complex-numbers, recurrence-relations, nested-radicals, analytic-continuation

I’m submitting this question because my [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772119/a-nested-radical-arising-from-a-nonlinear-recurrence) was perhaps too verbose and did not get the point very quickly.

A well known $\sqrt{2}$ nested radical has the following solutions as found in the literature [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical) and/or [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2005.11920256):

$$R_n(x)= \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2\ldots+\sqrt{2+x}}}}=\left\{
\begin{array}
\\2\cos(\cos^{-1}(x/2)\cdot2^{-n}) & \mbox{for} & |x|\le2\\
\\
b(x)^{2^{-n}}+b(x)^{-2^{-n}} & \mbox{for} & |x|\ge2\\
\end{array}\right.
$$

where

$$b(x)=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}$$

However, we have found that for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$

$$R_n(z)= \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2\ldots+\sqrt{2+z}}}}=\left\{
\begin{array}
\\2\cos(\cos^{-1}(z/2)\cdot2^{-n})
\\ \mbox{or eqivalently,}\\
b(z)^{2^{-n}}+b(z)^{-2^{-n}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

How can this be proven? This was derived from a recurrence relation, thence analytically continued. Is that sufficient? Otherwise, how would you go about proving it?

Comment: Instead of reposting I think you should go and edit your previous question (or delete it).

Comment: Of course if we're only considering real values and real functions, then $\cos^{-1}(x/2)$ isn't defined for $|x|>2$ and $\sqrt{x^2-4}$ isn't defined for $|x|<2$.

Comment: @bobeyt6 I appreciate your comment, but there is a lot of information on the recurrence relation that some may to refer to.

Comment: @aschepler But that's the point of my solution. $\cos^{-1}(x/2)$ and $\sqrt{x^2-4}$ are indeed defined over the entire complex plane. For example, if you want $y=\cos^{-1}(z)$ for arbitrary $z$, you can show that $y=-i*\log(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})$. Likewise, for $|x|\lt2$, $\sqrt{x^2-4}=i*\sqrt{|x^2-4|}$.

Comment: Understood. Just pointing out that's probably why the original has the two cases rather than just one of them.